# wordpress won't display posts

Tags: wordpress

The problem I have is I cannot get Wordpress to show the posts where I need to.

I have already tried using two methods the first in the reading settings by selecting a page to display the posts which did not work. The second was a getpost plugin which displays the post using short code [get_posts] it didn't display any post just the short code and the plugin is active.

I want it to appear like this http://www.completesource.co.uk/category/ironkey-id-theft/ but on this page http://beta.completesource.co.uk/it-news/

I have been searching for this for a while any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

EDIT: code

```
<?php
if (is_page() ) {
$category = get_post_meta($posts[0]->ID, 'category', true);
}
if ($category) {
$cat = get_cat_ID($category);
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$post_per_page = -1; // -1 shows all posts
$do_not_show_stickies = 1; // 0 to show stickies
$args=array(
'category__in' => array($cat),
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'DESC',
'paged' => $paged,
'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page,
'caller_get_posts' => $do_not_show_stickies
);
$temp = $wp_query;  // assign orginal query to temp variable for later use   
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args); 
if( have_posts() ) : 
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?     php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> <!-- by <?php the_author() ?> --></small>
    <div class="entry">
      <?php the_excerpt('Read the rest of this entry »'); ?>
     <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Read More..</a>
     <BR><BR>
    </div>

  </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('« Older Entries') ?></div>
  <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries »') ?></div>
</div>
 <?php else : ?>
    <h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
<p class="center">Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
<?php endif; 
$wp_query = $temp;  //reset back to original query
  }  // if ($category)
 ?>
```

Comment: Post a representative (aka SMALL) sample of your code. Otherwise this problem is essentially impossible to help with.

Comment: Which part would you like to see?

Comment: Marc is right - we need some more info. I'd first check under your settings > Reading and verify those are correct for your theme. If you're rolling your own theme, make sure you're calling "the loop" and not displaying static content. To assist us: what theme are you using. If your own - show us some code in the loop area/homepage which calls the loop.

Comment: I believe this is what you are asking for.

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
  
   <div class="entry">
    <?php the_content('<p class="serif">Read the rest of this page &raquo;</p>'); ?>

    <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p><strong>Pages:</strong> ', 'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>

   </div>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
 <?php edit_post_link('Edit this entry.', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>

Comment: Please edit your post, and put that code into the body so we can easily read it.

Comment: Updated with the code there now

Comment: I think I may be misunderstanding what you're trying to do. Do you want to change the URL permalink structure to remove "category" from the URL? So it would be: www.mydomain.com/category-a and not: www.mydomain.com/category/category-a, right?

Comment: No If you look at the two websites I posted I want to copy the format the posts are on the first site and place it on the second. The problem is that I can't get the posts to display at all on the second site IT News page.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would write a page template for the page, then create a new page and use the template. Start reading about [Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) and go from there.

Comment: I assume you clicked the new page option in the admin panel. That is the second step of what I am suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Every Wordpress theme on the market will handle the display of posts very differently. It can very by page, shortcode, template, settings, etc.

We need to know what theme you are using in order to help you. In order to help yourself, investigate how to activate the blog by checking your themes document files or the theme developer or any help forums for the theme.

Comment: I am using a custom theme which has been applied. This is becoming very frustrating for me now. I have access to the site I want it to look like but can't find anything within it to help me with what I need

Comment: So are you telling me your created your own wordpress theme? You built it yourself from the ground up? If so, will this help you then?http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: I wish then I wouldn't have this problem I came in after someone else had established the site but didn't finish the job. I have experience using wordpress as a CMS but struggling with the posts

Comment: uh oh, you may want to consider using a professional theme like genesis, thesis or thematic. It won't hurt anything to install and try out the site with a new theme, may solve your problem instantly!

Comment: I have posted the code in the original post if you wish to take a look